# Testing using training data

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

I've been trying to prove that estimates of a classifier's performance using training data is a bad thing.
Does "bad" mean it is biased?
This is part of a larger proof.

If somebody knows of previous work that proves this or a quick proof, any pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Yakka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue goes beyond any particular model, like a classifier, to statistical models in general. When you fit a model to training data, you are optimizing its fit or performance relative to that training set. Now, if you took that model and applied to different data, then unless the new data looks exactly like your training set, the performance will uaually be worse.

You can see this even with just the trainig data by running your classifier on a boostrap [sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) of your training set. You'll see that your traning set performance was biased high.

Comment: Thanks Eupraxis1981.
The problem I'm facing is that intuitively mixing testing and training data seems like a bad idea (and empirical results show this is true), but can it be formally proved.

Comment: I see. I don't have a paper to reference, but as a pointer, note that, if you have achieve a particular accuracy, say MSE, on a training set using for a particular classifier (C), you are essentially saying $\hat E[(y-C)^{2}] = \frac{1}{N}\sum (y_{i}-C(y_{i}))^{2}$ where the $y_{i}$ are the training sets you are classifying. The accuracy of C under that training set is limited by how close you can get C properly classify each $y_{i}$. However, the real goal is to get a good classifier for y, which is a random variable.

Comment: Therefore, if we took repeated samples from the distribution of y, then the true MSE of C would be: $E[(y-C)^{2}] = E[((y_{i}+\delta_{i})-C(y_{i}+\delta_{i}))^{2}]$ where $\delta_{i}$ is a random error term indicating the difference between your training set i and the ith real-world sample. Since $\delta_{i}$ has a positive variance, $E[(y_{i}-C(y_{i}))^{2}] < E[((y_{i}+\delta_{i})-C(y_{i}+\delta_{i}))^{2}]$ so you will have underestimated the variability, or overestimated the accuracy.

Comment: Wow... that's a very interesting line of thinking... I think I can apply it to my situation...
Superb, coupled with Theja's references this will work nicely :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Estimates of a classifiers performance using training data is "bad" because the same data was used to fit the model to optimize the performance metric in the first place.

This means that this performance metric may be very different from the metric when evaluated using the true distribution $\mu_{X}$ of the data source.

Use of testing data or cross validation is a technique to approximate this true metric under $\mu_X$.

Research pointer:

- Statistical learning theory answers the following question. When is the true metric for the fitted model close to the true metric of the best model possible (Bayes optimal or best in class)? Obviously this skips the question of "badness" of using an in-sample performance metric.
- In sample vs out of sample performance is discussed in [Page 9 of this](http://www.pedz.uni-mannheim.de/daten/edz-ki/ezb/02/w-paper/ecbwp195.pdf). Also check [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29).
- This paper by [Hansen](http://economics.uchicago.edu/pdf/Hansen_workshop_paper.pdf) essentially shows that for a variety of modeling problems, in sample performance and out of sample performance are negatively correlated (loosely speaking, check the abstract for definitions).

Comment: Thanks Theja, I'll follow those pointers and see if any of them have what I'm looking for.

Comment: The Hansen paper and White paper (page 9) are very close to what I was looking for. Thanks again.